# Linq to Entities Query explanation

Tags: linq, entities

Is there any way I can make this Linq to entities query in another way (better) and understand what I did?

First, can I have the `string.jon()` in the first part `(select(p => new {...)`?

Second, why do I need the first select to end with `.ToList()` for the `string.join()` to work?

The tables relation are as follow:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
Productos.Select(p => new { 
                  Id = p.Id,
                  Code = p.CodigoProd,
                  Name = p.Nombre,
                  Cant = p.Inventario.Sum(i => i.Cantidad),
                  Pric = p.Inventario.OrderBy(i => i.Precio).Select (i => i.Precio).FirstOrDefault(),
                  cate =  p.ProductosXCategoria.Select(pc => pc.CategoriasdeProducto.Nombre)
                }).Where (p => p.Cant != null).ToList()
                .Select (r => new {
                    r.Id, r.Code, r.Cant, r.Name, r.Pric, Categ = string.Join("-",r.cate)
                })
```

the result is this (which is the result i expected to be):

```
IEnumerable<> (17 items)   
**Id--  Code--  Cant--  Name--  Pric--  Categ**

1-- AXI--   30--    Pepsi-- 10--    Granos

3-- ASI--   38--    Carne blanca--  12--    Granos-Limpieza
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks fine to me.

The reason you can't move the `string.Join` method to the first `Select`, is that LINQ-to-Entities ultimately has to be able to translate to SQL. `string.Join` has no direct translation to SQL, so it doesn't know how to translate your LINQ query to it. By calling `ToList()` first, you bring the results of the first `Select` into memory, where the subsequent `Select` works with Linq-to-Objects. Since Linq-to-Objects does not need to translate to SQL, it can operate directly on the results of the first query in memory.

Generally, you would want to put everything that would be better left to SQL *before* the `ToList()` call (such as filtering, sorting, averaging, grouping, etc.), and leave additional work that can't be translated to SQL (or isn't as efficient to do so) for after the results have been brought into local memory.

Comment: I really appreciate your time to answer this question. I could not be more happy to receive support in my first question. Thanks A Lot From Honduras. I cannot vote, it says 15 reputation but Thanks.